# Approximation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n(1+\frac{c}{xn})^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

I have to show that
$$ 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n(1 + \frac{c}{xn})^n \leq \big(\frac{1}{1-x}\big)^{1 + c},~0<x<1,~c>0. $$

**My attempt:**

Fact:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\alpha\choose n}x^n = (1+x)^{\alpha},~x,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}. $$
Now
\begin{align*} 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n(1 + \frac{c}{xn})^n &\leq  1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n(1 + \frac{c}{x})(1+\frac{c}{2x})\dots(1+\frac{c}{nx}) \\ &= 1  + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n(1 + \frac{c}{x})(2+\frac{c}{x})\dots(n+\frac{c}{x})\frac{1}{n!} \\ &= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-x)^n(-1 - \frac{c}{x})(-2 - \frac{c}{x})\dots(- n-\frac{c}{x})\frac{1}{n!} \\ &= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-x)^n(-(1 + \frac{c}{x}))(-(1 + \frac{c}{x}) - 1)\dots(- (1+\frac{c}{x}) - n +1)\frac{1}{n!} \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n{-(1 +\frac{c}{x}) \choose n} = (1 - x)^{-(1+\frac{c}{x})}.
\end{align*}

Is it correct solution?

Comment: Step 1: Edit your query to provide **background.**  That is, what is the source of the problem, a contest, book, class, ...  If from a book or class, what theorems or recently solved problems were you exposed to that you think **might** be pertinent here. ...see next comment.

Comment: Step 2: Experiment with small **easy to work with** sample values for $c$.  For example, you might consider $c = (1/3), c=(1/2), c = (3/4).$  Look for a pattern to emerge.  Try to spot the pattern.  Form a hypothesis.  Try to prove the hypothesis. ...See next comment

Comment: Step 3: Again, edit your query, to **show all of your work** from Step 2, along with any insights that you may have gleaned.  Personally, I would regard 30 minutes to an hour as a reasonable investment in Step 2.

Comment: @OliverDiaz If the OP had no way to investigate, then I would agree that it is reasonable for a hint to precede his showing any work.  That's not the case here.  Investigative **baby steps** are obvious, and 30 minutes to an hour is not onerous.  Also, re background, the OP has (in effect) presented the problem in a vacuum.

Comment: @user2661923:you are entitle to you opinion. I just think that that sort of behavior is too pedantic. If he OP has no idea where to start, a good hint instead of a a lecture on etiquette is more helpful. You don't have to solve the problem for him/her, just a friendly hint.

Comment: @OliverDiaz "...has no idea where to start..." Doesn't the **combination** of Step 1 + Step 2 give him a place to start?  Perhaps we should agree to disagree on this one.